# PHP fgets "noblock"?

Tags: php, irc

I'm trying to build a little command-line IRC client in PHP because I'm getting sick of all those clients having you click through twenty GUI popups/windows to connect to a new server.

Everything is working so far, but I'm stuck with the main loop that sends my input commands/messages to the server and receives the new data from it.

As PHP isn't very multi-task-friendly I have two autonomous PHP scripts running at the same time:

The input reader where I can enter my messages - it stores the current message in a text file.
The server listener/writer which receives new data and reads and clears the text file where the input reader stored my current command in.

However `fgets()` which I use to read new data from the server `pauses the script waiting until something new arrives`. 
So the input text file can't be read out until something new arrives from the server, which is not good.

- Is there some special function/option to help me out?

Comment: May I recommend `irssi`? http://irssi.org

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at streams, and especially [`stream_set_blocking`](http://php.net/stream_set_blocking).

EDIT: in fact, you can get rid of having two processes and do everything in one process. Use non-blocking reads and you should be fine.